# phpMyAdmin hangs while executing known good query (local WAMP server)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, left-join

I'm trying to run the following query from phpMyAdmin (on a local WAMP server):

```
SELECT  table2.AreaName, table2.Dialcode
FROM    table2
LEFT JOIN
master
ON      master.Dialcode = table2.Dialcode
WHERE   master.Dialcode IS NULL
```

I first tried on two tables with 4 entries in each and I got a result.

Now I'm trying (the same query) on my "real" tables with around 20000 entries each and I click on GO. During 5-6 seconds I have "Loading3 appearing in the middle but then nothing happen, no result, anything loading...

Any idea?

EDIT:

> SHOW INDEXES FROM MASTER
>
> Table Non_unique Key_name Seq_in_index Column_name Collation Cardinality Sub_part Packed Null Index_type
>
> master 1 Dialcode 1 Dialcode A 18731 NULL NULL YES BTREE

And the same thing for the table2.
I already created indexes of the tables on DialCode by clicking on the INDEX button in PhpMyadmin.

SOLUTION: Actually the query works fast, that's the treatment I do after which takes time.

Comment: Does the request timeout? I would suggest using [Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) for working locally instead of phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Actually I don't get any timeout but then I can't navigate into the menus, the page loads confinuously. I need to restart MySQL service. I will try Workbench and let you know

Comment: Have you looked to see if there are any helpful entries in the error log? Is there anything untoward when you look at current processes? Excessive memory or CPU usage?

Comment: I don't get anything in Phpmyadmin but in Workbench I get:
 > Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query after 600sec.
And nothing appears in the logs

Comment: This problem is often caused by MySQL seg faulting. Sometimes it can be rectified by simply recreating the tables. What MySQL version are you running?

Comment: My query was simply too long, more than a hour. i am looking into another solution.

Comment: Do you have suitable indices on the tables being joined? Add the output from `SHOW INDEXES FROM master` and `SHOW INDEXES FROM table2` to your question. On a small dataset like this it should not take long at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just created a very simple mock up of your scenario and it returns in 0.03s with 1M records in table2 and 70K records in master. You probably need to add indices to the fields used for the join -

```
ALTER TABLE `table2`
    ADD INDEX `IX_table2_dialcode`(`Dialcode`);

ALTER TABLE `master`
    ADD INDEX `IX_master_dialcode`(`Dialcode`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "real" table contains around 20000 entries. This causes phpmyadmin to "hang" while running the SQL.

To prevent this, limit your result set. i.e. just append `limit 0,5` to the SQL you were trying. This will fetch only the first 5 rows of the result set.